# Persist checkmark Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing a fitness based app, the user will select their workout and then be taken to a table view consisting the exercises for the selected workout. When the user taps the cell then I want a checkmark to appear to indicate that exercise has been completed. I have succeeded with this but now I want to persist the checkmark so  if the user closes the app then the checkmark will still be shown when it reopens and selects the workout again.

Any help would be much appreciated.

The table view VC is below,

Thank you in advance.

```
import UIKit

class workoutTableView: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var workoutTableView: UITableView!

    var navTitle: String = ""
    var workout = [String]()
    let tlabel = UILabel()
    var completed: [Bool] = []
    var saveString = String()
    var saveBool = Bool()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setWorkout()
        completed = [Bool](repeating: false, count: workout.count)
        workoutTableView.delegate = self
        workoutTableView.dataSource = self
        tlabel.text = navTitle
        tlabel.textAlignment = .center
        tlabel.font = UIFont(name: "Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 30)
        tlabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        navigationItem.titleView = tlabel
    }

    func setWorkout() {

        if navTitle == "The 600 Workout" {

          workout = The600Workout().workoutArray
        }

        if navTitle == "5 Days for Muscle" {

          workout = FiveDaysForMuscle().workoutArray

        }

        if navTitle == "Marathon Ready" {

          workout = MarathonReady().workoutArray
        }

        if navTitle == "HIIT @ Home" {

          workout = HIITAtHome().workoutArray
        }

        if navTitle == "Get Strong" {

          workout = GetStrong().workoutArray
        }

        if navTitle == "Body Weight Blast" {

          workout = BodyWeightBlast().workoutArray
        }

        if navTitle == "Bands Pump" {

          workout = BandsPump().workoutArray
        }

        if navTitle == "Quickie Warm up" {

          workout = QuickieWarmUp().workoutArray
        }

        if navTitle == "The Best Circuit Workout" {

          workout = TheBestCircuit().workoutArray
        }

        if navTitle == "The Gym HIIT Workout" {

          workout = GymHIIT().workoutArray
        }

        if navTitle == "The Ultimate Workout" {

          workout = UltimateWorkout().workoutArray

        }


        if navTitle == "Warm up For Weights" {

          workout = WarmUpForWeights().workoutArray
        }

        if navTitle == "6 Day Bro Split" {

          workout = SixDayBroSplit().workoutArray
        }

        if navTitle == "Explosive Workout" {

         workout = ExplosiveWorkout().workoutArray
        }

        if navTitle == "Strength Circuit" {

          workout = StrengthCircuit().workoutArray
        }

        if navTitle == "Killer Circuit" {

          workout = KillerCircuit().workoutArray
        }

        if navTitle == "Fitness Test" {

          workout = FitnessTest().workoutArray
        }

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return workout.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        completed[indexPath.row] = !completed[indexPath.row]
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = completed[indexPath.row] ?  .checkmark : .none
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "prototypeCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = workout[indexPath.row]
        cell.accessoryType = completed[indexPath.row] ?  .checkmark : .none
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 5
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        cell.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.3285208941, blue: 0.5748849511, alpha: 1)
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
        cell.textLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        cell.textLabel?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Please ignore the save string and save bool, they were part of my failed attempt :(

Comment: Actually you have to save the array of selected workouts separately for each type. This doesn't work with your way to keep the selected rows in one array. I recommend to save the entire workout data in a database like Core Data. And once again the bunch of consecutive `if` expressions (without `else`) is extremely inefficient. Be aware that all types are unnecessarily examined even if `navTitle` is `"The 600 Workout"`

Comment: Thank you, I amended the if/ else if statements. In regards to the persistence, when you say save them into a database do you mean the entire models or just the type? Thanks again

Comment: I mean the entire model

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create some sort of workout list contains some sort of value (probably an index for IndexPath later).  Then store either NSArray or NSDictionary in UserDefaults

Answer (score 0):

I would consider adding a struct to organize your workouts a little better. I did not test or completely rewrite the code for you, but hope this helps a little:

```
import Foundation

class workoutTableView: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    struct Workout {
        let id: Int
        let name: String
        let workouts: [String]
    }

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    var workouts: [Workout] = []
    var completed: [Int] = []
    let workoutsKey = "CompletedWorkoutIds"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.completed = defaults.object(forKey: workoutsKey) as? [Int] ?? [Int]()
    }

    ...

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let workout = self.workouts[indexPath.row]
        if let index = completed.index(of: workout.id) {
            self.completed.remove(at: index)
        } else {
            self.completed.append(workout.id)
        }
         defaults.set(self.completed, forKey: workoutsKey)

        // Update checkmark
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let workout = self.workouts[indexPath.row]
        if completed.contains(workout.id) {
            // Show checkmark
        }
    }
}
```