# Persist checkmark for selected model swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, persistence, codable

This is third time I've posted this issues and am yet to get a working response.

So I have a fitness app, the user selected one workout before it been displayed as table view, when a cell is selected I want it to show that cell(containing an exercise) as completed by marking it with a checkmark. this works fine but I am struggling with how to save that check mark when the app is terminated and re launched.

Below I have given an example of one of the workout models and the table view controller.

Please can someone try and solve this!!

Thank you.

Josh

Example model -

```
class The600Workout {

    var workoutArray = [

        Workout(exercise: "Don't forget to warm up before every workout!", completed: false),
        Workout(exercise: "Start with little/ no weight and work your way up", completed: false),
        Workout(exercise: "------------------------------------------------------------------", completed: false),
        Workout(exercise: "Pull ups | 25 Reps", completed: false),
        Workout(exercise: "Lunges | 50 Reps (Low weight)", completed: false),
        Workout(exercise: "Calf Raises | 50 Reps (Low weight)", completed: false),
        Workout(exercise: "Shoulder press | 50 Reps (Low weight)", completed: false),
        Workout(exercise: "Push ups | 50 Reps", completed: false),
        Workout(exercise: "Shrugs | 50 Reps (Low weight)", completed: false),
        Workout(exercise: "Leg raises | 50 Reps", completed: false),
        Workout(exercise: "Bench press | 50 Reps (Low weight)", completed: false),
        Workout(exercise: "More Pull ups | 25 Reps", completed: false),
        Workout(exercise: "Squats | 50 Reps (Low weight)", completed: false),
        Workout(exercise: "Incline Bench press | 50 Reps (Low weight)", completed: false),
        Workout(exercise: "Bicep curls | 50 Reps (Low weight)", completed: false),
        Workout(exercise: "Tricep pull downs | 50 Reps (Low weight)", completed: false),
    ]
}
```

Table view controller -

```
class workoutTableView: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var workoutTableView: UITableView!

    var navTitle: String = ""
    var workout = [Workout]()
    let tlabel = UILabel()
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setWorkout()
        workoutTableView.delegate = self
        workoutTableView.dataSource = self
        tlabel.text = navTitle
        tlabel.textAlignment = .center
        tlabel.font = UIFont(name: "Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 30)
        tlabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        navigationItem.titleView = tlabel
        }

    func setWorkout() {

        if navTitle == "The 600 Workout" {

            workout = The600Workout().workoutArray

        }

        else if navTitle == "5 Days for Muscle" {

          workout = FiveDaysForMuscle().workoutArray

        }

        else if navTitle == "Marathon Ready" {

          workout = MarathonReady().workoutArray
        }

        else if navTitle == "HIIT @ Home" {

          workout = HIITAtHome().workoutArray
        }

        else if navTitle == "Get Strong" {

          workout = GetStrong().workoutArray
        }

        else if navTitle == "Body Weight Blast" {

          workout = BodyWeightBlast().workoutArray
        }

        else if navTitle == "Bands Pump" {

          workout = BandsPump().workoutArray
        }

        else if navTitle == "Quickie Warm up" {

          workout = QuickieWarmUp().workoutArray
        }

        else if navTitle == "The Best Circuit Workout" {

          workout = TheBestCircuit().workoutArray
        }

        else if navTitle == "The Gym HIIT Workout" {

          workout = GymHIIT().workoutArray
        }

        else if navTitle == "The Ultimate Workout" {

          workout = UltimateWorkout().workoutArray
        }


         else if navTitle == "Warm up For Weights" {

            workout = WarmUpForWeights().workoutArray
        }

        else if navTitle == "6 Day Bro Split" {

          workout = SixDayBroSplit().workoutArray
        }

        else if navTitle == "Explosive Workout" {

         workout = ExplosiveWorkout().workoutArray
        }

        else if navTitle == "Strength Circuit" {

          workout = StrengthCircuit().workoutArray
        }

        else if navTitle == "Killer Circuit" {

          workout = KillerCircuit().workoutArray
        }

        else if navTitle == "Fitness Test" {

          workout = FitnessTest().workoutArray
        }

   }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return workout.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        workout[indexPath.row].completed = !workout[indexPath.row].completed
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = workout[indexPath.row].completed ?  .checkmark : .none
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "prototypeCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = workout[indexPath.row].exercise
        cell.accessoryType = workout[indexPath.row].completed ?  .checkmark : .none
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 5
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        cell.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.3285208941, blue: 0.5748849511, alpha: 1)
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
        cell.textLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        cell.textLabel?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)
        return cell

    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of continuing to re-ask the same question. How about you comment on the ones who have answered you on whats not working for you with the answer they provided. In the code example you have above you literally just added `let defaults = UserDefaults.standard` and are not using it. I answered this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59688268/12555191

Comment: Not to be rude, but your answer didn't solve my problem. I am yet to get a solution so thought posting it again would reach more developers who may be able to help. If this upsets you, feel free not to comment. Thank you for trying though!

Comment: Good luck man..

Comment: Don't repost questions. My answer in the duplicate shows you a reasonable way to solve the problem.